# Rails ActionController::BadRequest causes 500 Server Error on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, server-error

We have a Turkish website and some old links are crawled by some search engines. The links seem to be malformed or cannot be processed and therefore causing `ActionController::BadRequest` error. On the local machine with `development env` this causes to return the Rails error page with `ActionController::BadRequest`.

But on the Server we get an `500 server error`. This issues is discussed on several other pages like [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/588593-invalid-querystring-leads-to-status-500-typeerror-expected-hash-got-array-for-param). But none of the solutions helped.

In both cases we would like to redirect to a `page not found`-page.

I already tried to `rescue_from ActionController::BadRequest` and `rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError` in `ApplicationController` because of the aforementioned article, where they state that `BadRequest` turns into `RoutingError`.

But neither of them worked.

I hope someone had the same problem and already resolved it. Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Edit:**

One example problem-url is `http://localhost:3000/Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1`.

Terminal output:

```
ActionController::BadRequest (ActionController::BadRequest):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:37:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4278100521352222029__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  rollbar (0.11.7) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:19:in `call_with_rollbar'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:486:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:357:in `process_client'
  puma (2.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:250:in `block in run'
  puma (2.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
  puma (2.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Best regards

Comment: I had the same issue. An answer would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the stack trace?  also, does this answer do anything?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473964/2128691

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question, and I also tried that but it did not work either.

Comment: are you using config.exceptions_app? I still have no resolution: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15124

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue in a Rails 4.0.x app where it was polluting my New Relic error page.

I got around this by writing a middleware that caches the `ActionController::BadRequest` error, Logs it and returns a `400` error page. *(A 400 seemed more appropriate then a 404 error.)*

**app/middleware/catch_request_errors.rb**

```
class CatchRequestErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionController::BadRequest => error
      ::Rails.logger.warn("WARN: 400 ActionController::BadRequest: #{env['REQUEST_URI']}")
      @html_400_page ||= File.read(::Rails.root.join('public', '400.html'))
      [
          400, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" },
          [ @html_400_page ]
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "CatchRequestErrors"
```

**public/400.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your request could not be handled (400)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/400.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>Your request could not be handled.</h1>
    <p>Please check the url and post data for syntax errors.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This stops processing the rails stack, logs the error and returns the 400.html page to the user freeing the app to process a more valid request.

I'm also caching the 400 page as a instance variable to save on GC and Disc IO.

Comment: I sadly still get this error : An ActionController::BadRequest occurred in #:
 
  ActionController::BadRequest
  app/middleware/catch_request_errors.rb:8:in `call'

Comment: Rails 7: config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Callbacks, CatchRequestErrors

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that one of your routes or Rack middleware is invalid and causes the 500 error. In new Rails app there is no incorrect behaviour with url `http://localhost:3000/Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1` - app returns a 404 error as expected. Also request to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/?foo[]=array&foo[hash]=hash` return absolutely correct response with 400 error (BadRequest).

Try to rewrite routes like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/*path', :to => lambda { |env| [200, {}, [env.to_s]]}
  # omited
end
```

and take a look to response status - if it 200, than problem in your Rails application, otherwise anywhere else in the rack middleware.

`rails -v #=> Rails 4.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack. Put this code inside `initializers`

```
module Rack
  module Utils
    alias_method :original_normalize_params, :normalize_params
    module_function :original_normalize_params

    def normalize_params(params, name, v = nil)
      begin
        original_normalize_params(params, name, v)
      rescue => e
        raise ActionController::BadRequest.new("Incorrect URL")
      end
    end

    module_function :normalize_params
  end
end
```

It will respond with 400 for requests like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/?foo[]=array&foo[hash]=hash`

EDIT:

Also, it is possible to implement middleware which checks for correctness of parameters.

Catching bad queries by middleware

```
# config/application.rb

require File.expand_path('../../lib/query_validator', __FILE__)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # configurations

    config.middleware.insert_before('ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions', QueryValidator)
  end
end

# lib/query_validator.rb

class QueryValidator
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])

      env['QUERY_STRING'].valid_encoding? or
        raise ActionController::BadRequest, "Invalid parameter: #{env['QUERY_STRING']}"
    rescue => e
      env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
      env['my_app.query_errors'] = 'Invalid query.'
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end


# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter do
    if env['my_app.query_errors']
      flash[:alert] = env['my_app.query_errors']
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you. But can you explain how to use this code exactly? I  created a file ./config/initializers/bad_request_hack.rb and put the code in there, and when I restarted the server nothing changed. Actually when I used your url-example `/?foo[]=array&foo[hash]=hash` it says `undefined method BadRequest`. If I use my url `/Eskisehir/indirimler/Di%c5%c3%af%c2%bf%c2%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1` I get the same error as before.

Comment: My fail, fixed code: `raise ActionController::BadRequest.new("asd", e)`

Comment: Now for your url I get `Invalid asd parameters: expected Hash (got Array) for param `foo'` and my url is the same. And can you tell me what the "asd" does?

Comment: Instead of "asd" you can write message: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/BadRequest/new/class

I've fixed `raise ActionController::BadRequest.new("Incorrect URL")` without `, e` in `BadRequest.new("asd", e)`

Comment: Thank you works fine for your url but the one I presented still raises Bad Request.

Comment: Added example using middleware, it should help

Comment: As I understand it my malformed url should be causing `BadRequest` and rescue in `query_validator.rb` shall return an error. But if I add your code I get the `BadRequest` error at the `@app.call(env)` line, which means the parsing just worked. Do you need more information? I am really grateful and you seem to know what is going on so I hope you can help me

Comment: But in your question you said you need 400 BadRequest on production environment. If you don't need error, just remove query: `env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''`. I've updated the example above.

Comment: Basically you are right. Maybe I phrased it incorrectly. On `development` I get 400 Error and on `production` I get 500 error which causes the server to shut down. If an user or a search engine accesses the app via a malformed url it should just got to the `page not found page` of the app. I used `get "*path", to: 'errors#page_not_found'` to forward all not mentioned urls in routes file to the `page not found` but unfortunately it does not affect the aforementioned urls. Should I change the question above to get a better answer? Sry I am quite new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Then you need update the question. I think the code I given you should fix this problem though. It redirects malformed urls to `root_path`, of course you can change redirection to page not found page.

Comment: Ok, you are right it redirects to the page I want, but only for your presented url `/?foo[]=array&foo[hash]=hash` the url which causes us problems is `/Silifke/indirimler/Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1` which still raises `Bad Request`. I think the `parse_nested_query` function does not raise an error with our url. I read that bad request means also the url could be url-conform but not processed from ruby, maybe that is the problem. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Bth, I have no idea what url-conform is. I've tested the code above with url `http://localhost/test?Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1`. It redirects as expected. May be you have issue in your controller. Also, you can find which method raises an error and catch exception of the method as I did with `parse_nested_query `. Can you update stack trace? I think it is not full, or is it?

Comment: Don't try it as a get parameter instead it is part of the url-path-component like `localhost:3000/Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1`. Because you are right if I put it after the `?` it works. But if not I get the exception at `@app.call(env)` in the `query_validator.rb` therefore it would have no sense to catch the exception again because the rescue-block is skipped.

Comment: I've tried the url `localhost:3000/Di%c5%ef%bf%bd-f%c4%b1r%c3%a7as%c4%b1` and it returns `404 not found` as expected. Btw, I am using `rails 4.1.0`.

Comment: We use `rails 4.0.0` and upgrading would be really much work. I tested it and it does not work. Do you know another way to solve the problem under `4.0.0`?

Comment: I've tested on `4.0.0` and it returns `404 not found` without `QueryValidator`. What kind of error do you get? May be you have issues with encoding? Can you update your stack trace?

Comment: I updated the `Full Trace` of the error page. I dont know if it really changed as I did not compared it line by line. I also added the `env dump` of the error page.

Comment: Can you put your erros like this `https://gist.github.com/Zhomart/887aaa411b5dd2035571`? I want to see the error.

Comment: I added the terminal output instead of the output from the rails-error page. Is this what you wanted? Because else I don't get the difference between the error example of you and the thing I posted.