# Handling Rails ActionController::BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, bad-request

So, going to `http://localhost:3000/%ED` will throw `ActionController::BadRequest`.

But what I really want if return a 404 page (like most websites do).

For instance, [Twitter](https://twitter.com/%ED) will say:

> Invalid Unicode value in one or more parameters /%ED

And me I get that in development (and a 500 error page in production):

[image: going to localhost:3000/%ED]

I tried the obvious `rescue_from` but the error doesn't even it my application as it's raised in the routing stack.

Any idea? I thought about a middleware but doesn't know how I would do it?

Comment: What you want is to be able to redirect to a 404 page in routes.rb. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653761/how-redirect-to-404-page-in-routes-rb

Comment: Thanks, so I need to use `config.exceptions_app = self.routes`? But then how do I know I got a 404 or a 500? And will it still report the exception? Also, that may be a bad idea, as if there is an error in my application, trying to use my application may generate even more errors?

Comment: I added an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26227688/516820 basically I have a middleware that catches the error and returns a `400` error page.

Comment: I actually found the answer by using utf8-cleaner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26242215/407213 I recommend it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [`utf8-cleaner`](https://github.com/singlebrook/utf8-cleaner) and it works really fine.